# How to do countif not duplicate and not blank in Excel and not a number?

Tags: excel

Say if I have the following data in Column A

```
A1 = a
A2 = a
A3 = b
A4 = b
A5 = 1
A6 blank 
A7 = d
```

I would like to count item on column A, if it's not duplicate and not blank and not a number.
If anyone knows, please help.

Comment: so is the answer 2 (1 for c and 1 for d?) or 4 (1 for a, 1 for b, 1 for c, and 1 for d)?

Comment: So you just want to count uniques, not including numbers?

Comment: Yes, I want to count only the unique value, but not numbers.

Comment: =countifs is what you are looking for. Not sure about the unique part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given your example data above, this returns the expected answer (3):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISTEXT(A1:A7))/COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7&""))
```

as commented by @Jeeped, [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2003-excel/count-unique-with-sumproduct-breakdown/1bc18979-4172-4537-993e-3897f74d6a5b) is a link w/ an explanation as to how the formula works.

Comment: [Count Unique with SUMPRODUCT()](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2003-excel/count-unique-with-sumproduct-breakdown/1bc18979-4172-4537-993e-3897f74d6a5b)

Comment: @pnuts - Probably both tags would be more in keeping with current ebb and flow of categorizing questions; `Excel` as a primary tag and `Excel-Formula` as a subset. My comment above was simply to help sous2817 in case the OP wanted an explanation of how it works.